# String of coordinates to array

Tags: c#

I have the following string and I want to convert it to an array in the best way

`string coordinates = "\n            34.8802346,31.9673726,0\n          "`

It comes to me in this strange way because that's how it's extracted from `KML`

```
<Placemark xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <name>Mall</name>
  <styleUrl>#icon-959-795046-labelson-nodesc</styleUrl>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>
            34.8802346,31.9673726,0
    </coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>

string coordinates = placeMark.Elements(ns + "Point").Select(i => i.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `.Trim().Split(',')` would give you an array of strings

Comment: comvert to array on what critaria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty trivial - use [`String.Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-7.0) to remove white-spaces characters and then [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0):

```cs
var strings = coordinates.Trim().Split(','); // array of strings - [34.8802346, 31.9673726, 0]
```

Comment: @OrLevi it depends on actual logic. If you are interested only in first 2 elements - you can use some LINQ - for example `coordinates.Trim().Split(',').Take(2).ToArray()`